# How can I pass srcObject in videoElement using ReactHook?

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a dynamic element of video in React using hook `createElement`, but I don't know how can I pass srcObject in that element. Check my code below and guide me.

```
const addVideoElement = (videoObject) => {
   const element = React.createElement("video", { srcObject: videoObject});
   ReactDOM.render(element, document.getElementById("video"));
};
```

Any solution appreciated!

Comment: First param of React.createElement need to be a Component or string if html tag
React.createElement("div", { srcObject: videoObject}, null)
React.createElement(MyComponent, { srcObject: videoObject}, null)

Comment: @AurelioLIMAFERREIRA video is a element

Answer (score 0):

React.createElement takes three params (Component, props, children) [DOC](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-without-jsx.html)

if Component is html tag use string like : "div"

```
const MyComponentVideo = (props) =>
 <video controls={props.controls} width={props.width}>
  <source src="props.src" type="props.type"/>
 </video>

const addVideoElement = (videoObject) => {
   const Element = React.createElement(MyComponentVideo, { ...someProps }, null);
   ReactDOM.render(Element, document.getElementById("video"), null);
};
```

or

```
export default () => {
  const Source = React.createElement("source",{src:"https://urlSource"}, null);
  const Video = React.createElement("video", null, Source);
  return ReactDOM.render(Video, document.getElementById("video"));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function App(){
   const addVideoElement = (srcObject)=> {
      ReactDOM.render(
        <SrcObjectVideo srcObject={srcObject} />,
        document.getElementById('video')
      )
   }
   ...
}
function SrcObjectVideo({ srcObject }){
  const ref = React.useRef();
  React.useEffect(() => {
    ref.current.srcObject = srcObject;
  }, [srcObject]);
  return <video ref={ref} />
}
```

or use URL.createObjectURL https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL

```
const addVideoElement = (srcObject)=> {
   ReactDOM.render(
     <video src={URL.createObjectURL(srcObject)} />, 
     document.getElementById('video')
   )
}
```